# Same conditional branch keeps being executed regardless of user input

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm trying to write the basic code for a random name generator in Python. This will soon become a fully working web application with an easy-to-use GUI but for some reason the program doesn't work.

When I run the program, it asks the user to specify either "console" or "game". When I enter "game" it still carries on with the **if** route instead of the **else** route.

```
import string
#This is a Name Generato
print("Welcome To the first version of my name generator at the moment there is only 20 names but in the final version there will be 200 names with over 25 different tags")
print("First of all what do you need a Console or a game Name?")
console = input()

if (console):
    print("is it a,PS4,PS3,XBOX 360,XBOX ONE or PC")
    print("NOTE:Wii,PSP and DS are not supported")
    consolename = input()
    print("The,",consolename)
    print("Is good")
    print ("now give me one or two key words that you would like in your name out of...")
    print("happy,sad,depressed,fox,cow,cat,dog,wolf,lion,lil,lazy,forgetful,gaming,xxx,orthodox,apex,toXic")
    firstname1=input()
    secondname=input()
    print(firstname1)
    print(secondname)
    print("Good Choice")
else: 
    print("What game is it?")
    print("Minecraft,Black ops 1//2/3,COD,Halo1/2/3/4/5/CE/Reach,Terraria,World of warcraft,League Of Legends")
    print("NOTE:Type the Game As you see it!")
    game1 = input()
    print("Ah good choice eh")
```

Comment: console is a string. It is always "truthy". Compare with the string!!

Comment: The `console` string will only be `False` if it is empty.  For that just hit <RETURN> at the `input()`.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a string input and you are checking if its True which is always true if its not empty. You need to compare your console variable to a string. Something like this will do the job.

```
import string
#This is a Name Generato
print("Welcome To the first version of my name generator at the moment there is only 20 names but in the final version there will be 200 names with over 25 different tags")
print("First of all what do you need a Console or a game Name?")
console = input()

if (console=="console" or console=="Console"):
    print("is it a,PS4,PS3,XBOX 360,XBOX ONE or PC")
    print("NOTE:Wii,PSP and DS are not supported")
    consolename = input()
    print("The,",consolename)
    print("Is good")
    print ("now give me one or two key words that you would like in your name out of...")
    print("happy,sad,depressed,fox,cow,cat,dog,wolf,lion,lil,lazy,forgetful,gaming,xxx,orthodox,apex,toXic")
    firstname1=input()
    secondname=input()
    print(firstname1)
    print(secondname)
    print("Good Choice")
else: 
    print("What game is it?")
    print("Minecraft,Black ops 1//2/3,COD,Halo1/2/3/4/5/CE/Reach,Terraria,World of warcraft,League Of Legends")
    print("NOTE:Type the Game As you see it!")
    game1 = input()
    print("Ah good choice eh")
```

Comment: Also a good idea for OP to change the variable name to something other than `console`.

Comment: Yep this code needs lots of changes. But at this point its better for OP to understand the "IF" statement.